# How can I select which tags should be stripped from the footer?

Tags: 6

In Drupal 6, the footer message is stripped of some HTML tags. In my case I want to place `<img>` with a `<map>` tag so the image would link to different sections. Drupal strips off the `<map>` tag, even if I add it to the accepted HTML tags in "Filtered HTML" data type.

Is there a way to enable the `<map>` tag in the footer?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about a custom block that you add in the footer region of the site. In that case, you need to include all the HTML tags used to create a map image, which are `<area>`, `<img>`, and `<map>`.

I have tried with a block contained the following HTML.

```
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Once I enable those HTML tags for the *Filtered HTML* input format, the HTML added to the page for that block is the following.

```
<div id="block-block-1" class="clear-block block block-block">


  <div class="content"><p><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" /></p>
<p><map name="planetmap"><br />
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/sun.htm" alt="Sun" /><br />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" /><br />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/venus.htm" alt="Venus" /><br />
</map></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that, since the function Drupal used to filter out HTML tags is [filter_xss()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/filter_xss/6), the HTML you pass to the *Filtered HTML* input format is altered to:

- Remove characters and constructs that can trick browsers
- Make sure all HTML entities are well-formed
- Make sure all HTML tags and attributes are well-formed
- Make sure no HTML tags contain URLs with a disallowed protocol (e.g. `javascript:`)

Then, also [_filter_xss_attributes()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/_filter_xss_attributes/6) is called; that means also tag attributes are filtered.

Comment: Resisting...urge...to...remove...link...to...w3fools...